# xmgrace: bar graph vizualisation using batch

Tags: bash, gnuplot, plotting, xmgrace

I am using xmgrace to plot 2D bar plot from the following input data:

```
@ title "H-bonds"
@ xaxis label "Donor"
@ yaxis label "Frac"
@s0 line type 0
@s0 symbol linewidth 1
@s0 symbol fill pattern 1
@s0 symbol fill color 4
@TYPE bar
@XAXIS TICK MAJOR 1
GLU_166@N 0.6865
HIE_163@NE2 0.4160
ASN_142@ND2 0.0788
THR_25@OG1 0.0109
```

as you may see all grace's options have already defined in the @ comments. so to produce the graph I need only to execute

```
gracebat .dat -hdevice PNG -fixed 800 600 -world 0 0 5 1.0 -printfile test.png -hardcopy
```

the problem is that the produced bar graph does not contain any information about the labels from the first columns (like THR_26@OG1 etc), producing something like
[image]

1. visualization of the X labels: how could I use the labels on the X from the original data file instead of the values printed on default 1,2,3 etc ? I found the possibility to rename manually the X labels in gui but still have not find the command for batch execution.

2. visualization of the Y labels: would it be possible to plot the values of the fraction (Y) just above each bar directly on the bar graph (now they are indicated only on the Y)?